# What does Mobius group/transformations have to do with special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, mathematical-physics, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, twistor

The group of Mobius transformations, denoted by ${\rm Mob}(2,\mathbb{C})$, is *isomorphic* to ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C}))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ which in turn is *isomorphic* to the Lorentz group ${\rm SO}^+(3,1)$.

This connection, to me, seems very intriguing. After all, Mobius transformation is the most general, one-to-one, conformal map of the Riemann sphere to itself, given by $$w=f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\tag{1}$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary complex constants satisfying $(ad-bc)=1$. Apparently, (1) has nothing to do with spacetime transformations.

But the aforementioned isomorphism makes me curious whether there is any deep physical consequence(s) related to this isomorphism.

Comment: See the Appendix "Topology" in Weinberg's QFT, Vol.1, chapter 2.

Comment: This is not special to the 2d sphere. The Moebius group of global conformal transformations of Euclidean $d$ dimensional space is essentially $SO(d+1,1)$. In the Minkowski case, then it would be $SO(d,2)$.

Answer (score 6):

1. A future-directed light-ray $$n^{\mu}~=~(1,{\bf p}/|{\bf p}|), \qquad {\bf p}~\in~\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{\bf 0\}, \tag{1}$$ can be identified with a non-zero future-directed light-like 4-vector $$p^{\mu}~=~(E,{\bf p})\tag{2}$$ if we mod out with the energy $E\equiv |{\bf p}|>0$.
2. Therefore the set of future-directed light-rays (through a fiducial point) can be identified with the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) $$\mathbb{C}P^1~\cong~S^2~\cong~(\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{\bf 0\})/\mathbb{R}_+.\tag{3}$$
3. The restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(3,1)$ acts transitively on the set of future-directed light-rays, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291201/2451). Hence they can be identified with Moebius transformations.
4. For a proof of $SO^+(3,1)\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2$, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 5):

You'll find an intuitive way into your question via the [Wiki article on Möbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

"*In physics, the identity component of the Lorentz group acts on the celestial sphere in the same way that the Möbius group acts on the Riemann sphere. In fact, these two groups are isomorphic. An observer who accelerates to relativistic velocities will see the pattern of constellations as seen near the Earth continuously transform according to infinitesimal Möbius transformations. This observation is often taken as the starting point of twistor theory.*"

See also the late section on Applications, which discusses the isomorphism of the Möbius group with the Lorentz group, SO+(1,3) and SL(2,C). Also the classification table near the end, which I find suggestive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, to someone, for countering one of yesterday's two downvotes.

Comment: +1 from me because this answer is certainly correct, and your contribution is valuable.  I don't think this deserves downvotes at all.  But if I had to guess, I would think maybe the downvoters felt that this answer didn't get into enough specifics (unlike Qmechanic's answer).  So while this is good, maybe you could work to increase the detail in your future answers.  Also, you probably shouldn't guess who downvotes you.  I would be very surprised if Qmechanic was one of them because he'll surely understand the answer; downvoters on a correct answer basically never understand the answer.

Comment: @Mike , I greatly appreciate your encouraging reply and concede that I my answer didn't get into as much detail as others can provide, but I learnt something from writing it, and hoped it would provide an easy way in for the OP and others at a level like mine (chemist with strong interest in physics, but much maths still to learn).