# $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation of $SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, group-representations, lorentz-symmetry

The representation $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$  of the Lorentz group correspond to a four- vector or a spin-one object. Right? Does it imply that any four-vector is *identical to* a spin-one object or any scalar is *identical to* a spin-0 object? This can't be correct, right? Because although $A^\mu$ is a four vector and a spin-one object at the same time (which is photon), there is no concept of spin associated with $p^\mu$ or $J^\mu$. I'm confused by terminologies of representation.

Edit- How can I show that $A^\mu$ represent a spin-1 object?

Comment: Technically, the representation $\left(\frac 12, \frac 12\right)$ is either for the group $\mbox{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ or for the group $\mbox{SU}(2,\mathbb C) \times \mbox{SU}(2,\mathbb C)$, i.e. it's not a representation of the Lorentz group into a finite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is with the identification of the $(A,B)$ values of a representation with spin. $A$ and $B$ do not correspond to spin (they are not even Hermitian!), they just happen to obey $SU(2)$ Lie algebras, and as such they add up in the same way that spins do. When we say that $A_\mu,J_\mu,p_\mu,...$ are all in the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) $ representation of the Lorentz group we mean that they transform as a four-vector, that's all. People may get lazy and say they are spin 1 objects, but what they really mean is $(A,B)$ spin 1 objects.

Answer (score 18):

I) Firstly, we are talking about the [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) or [Cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) product $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ of groups, not the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)$^1$ $SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$ of groups.

II) Secondly, $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ is not isomorphic to the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$ but rather to a compact cousin

$$[SU(2)\times SU(2)]/\mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~ SO(4).$$

In particular, a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ irrep under $su(2)\oplus su(2)$ corresponds to a 4-dimensional fundamental vector representation under $o(4)$.

III) Thirdly, OP might be thinking of the complexified Lorentz group $SO(3,1;\mathbb{C})$, which has double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$,

$$[SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})]/\mathbb{Z}_2~\cong~ SO(3,1;\mathbb{C}).$$

cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post. In particular, a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ irrep under $sl(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ corresponds to a 4-dimensional fundamental vector representation under $o(3,1;\mathbb{C})$.

--

$^1$ Note that there exist various [Abelian](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+abelian+groups) and [non-Abelian](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_groups) tensor product constructions for groups. E.g. for the Abelian group $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$, the tensor product is $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^m\cong \mathbb{R}^{nm}$, while the Cartesian product is $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

Comment: -@Qmechanic♦ -Is there a difference between cartesian product and tensor product? I thought they are same and also same as direct product.

Comment: How does the dirac spinor transform in terms of $SO(3,1)$? I thought $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ is the double cover of $SO^+(3,1)$ (the connected component of the lorentz group), and so the left and ring hand weyl spinor correspond to the fundamental rep of $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$. But according to your post, $(1/2,1/2)$ irrep corresponds to the 4-dim vector rep.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac The left handed weyl spinor irrep is $(1/2, 0)$ while the right-handed weyl spinor irrep is $(0,1/2)$.  The irrep $(1/2, 1/2)$ is distinct from these and is equivalent to the vector rep.