# Show the Lie algebra is the same for $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ and Lorentz group

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory

So I know:
$$[\sigma_{I},\sigma{j}] = 2i \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_{k}$$
So two products of this should give us the Lorentz group:
$SO(4) = SU(2) \times SU(2)$

Where $SO(4)$ has 3 Lie algebra which can be expressed as one by denoting:
$$J_{I}^{\pm} = \frac{1}{2} (J_{I} \pm ik_{I})$$

This gives two Lie algebra:
$$[J_{I}^{\pm}, J_{j}^{\pm}] = i\epsilon_{ijk}J_{k}^{\pm}$$

But how is this related to our original product of SU(2)? I was under the impression if you have two Lie groups, $(g_{1},h_{1})$ and $(g_{2}, h_{2})$, then the product would be $(g_{1}g_{2},h_{1}h_{2})$. However, I tried that with the Pauli matrices and it doesn't work to be the same as $SO(4)$ Lie algebra. How should this be done?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3646/11127 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99283/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108212/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A nitpick: QFT and its notations are not too wonted or known to me, but as an outsider I get confused when you call $SO(4)$ the Lorentz group. Do you mean to say $SO(3,\,1)$ (*i.e.* nontrivial signature)?

Comment: The conclusion of your first statement is NOT correct. As Lie groups
$$ SU(2) \times SU(2) \neq SO(4) $$
rather
$$ (SU(2) \times SU(2)) / \mathbb{Z}_2 \simeq SO(4) $$
As Lie algebras 
$$ \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(4) $$
These are inequivalent statements, albeit they are closely related.