# Why does $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation of $SO(1,3)$ Lorentz group act on $2\times2$ Hermitian matrices?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

In pg. 81 of the Physics from Symmetry [book](http://www.infis.ufu.br/%7Egerson/grupos/3%20-%20Great%20books/Physics%20from%20Symmetry.pdf), the author deduced that the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$  representation of the Lorentz $SO(1,3)$ group acts on $2\times2$ Hermitain matrices using the following arguments:

- First assume that the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation acts on general  $2\times2$ matrices.
- Any $2\times2$ matrix can be written as a sum of a Hermitian and an anti-Hermitian matrix.
- Transformations in the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$  representation always transform a $2\times2$ Hermitian matrix into another $2\times 2 $ Hermitian matrix  and equivalently an anti-Hermitian matrix into another anti-Hermitian matrix.
- The above point tells us that the  if $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation acts on general $2\times2$ matrices, it is a reducible representation. But this contradicts the fact that the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation is irreducible.
- Thus the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation acts on $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices.

The leap in logic from the 4th to 5th point confuses me. Why can't the $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ representation act on $2\times2$ anti-Hermitian matrices?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160794/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The point is antihermitean matrices *A* map to hermitian ones *H* by 
$
H\equiv i A$,   so 
$A^\dagger = -A  \leftrightarrow H^\dagger = H,
$ so you didn't miss anything by ignoring the antihermitean block. Recall a real number multiplying a complex number!