# Are matrices in $\rm SU(2) \times \rm SU(4)$ unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, group-representations, unitarity

I want to ask about unitary group $\rm SU(2)$ and $\rm SU(4).$

From my reading, the matrix of $\rm SU(2)$ and $\rm SU(4)$ is unitary matrix.

I make the product of $\rm SU(4)\times SU(2)$

It is possible when I make an evolution, the matrix of $\rm SU(4)\times SU(2)$ is not unitary?

Comment: That's not the tensor product.  It's just the Cartesian product.

Comment: For an explanation of user1504's comment, see e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206840/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @user1504, how to make the cartesian product between SU(4)×SU(2) since it cannot be multiply because not same order. please help me

Comment: The cartesian product is the set of pairs $(g,h)$, with $g\in SU(4)$ and $h \in SU(2)$.   Multiplication on the Cartesian product is element-wise; $(g,h) (g',h') = (gg', hh')$.

Comment: it will have a 8x8 matrix? but how?. can u give me example for SU(2)xSU(2). and what it mean by g' and h'

Comment: $g$ and $g'$ are elements of $SU(4)$.  They're 4x4 unitary matrices of determinant 1.  $h$ and $h'$ are 2x2 unitary matrices of determinant 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible [..] the matrix of $\rm SU(4)\times SU(2)$ is not unitary?

No, it will be unitary. The tensor product of two unitary matrices is always unitary.

Proving that for yourself makes a good basic exercise, so I won't spoil it.

Comment: thank you very much. but I want to ask within the matrix in SU(4), the multiplication between the matrix is a normal matrix multiplication or not same? . If not, how the way to multiply them.