# Why are systems joined via a tensor product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, group-theory

This question comes from seeing that the triangle addition rule for quantum mechanics comes out of groups/representation theory; I thought this was odd as we haven't used any group ideas in QM up to this point. After thinking about it I realised/belive that it comes from the use of a tensor product.

In quantum mechanics if we have 2 systems (2 particles, a particle with spin and orbital wavefunctions etc) why do we join them as a tensor product and not a direct sum or cartesian product or a new 'quantum product'?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/50583

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/350508/2451 and links therein.