# Why the full conformal symmetry is $Vir\otimes \overline{Vir}$ instead of $Vir\oplus \overline{Vir}$

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, notation, lie-algebra

In 2D CFT, we have the Virasoro generators $L_m$ and the generators $\bar L_m$, which are such that $[L_m,\bar L_n]=0$. Hence I thought that the full conformal algebra was $Vir\oplus \overline{Vir}$. But I see in the literature that they write $Vir\otimes \overline{Vir}$ instead. The same happens in the more general case of a symmetry algebra $A\otimes \overline{A}$. Why is this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206840/50583 and its linked questions. The issue is that physicists don't use $\otimes$ consistently, but use it for any of (direct product, direct sum, tensor product).

Comment: Which literature? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic For example, page 71 of "Basic Concepts in String Theory", by Blumenhage, Lust and Theisen. There they refer to the extended symmetry algebra $A\otimes\bar A$.

Comment: If $A$ and $\overline{A}$ are supposed to be Lie algebras (Lie groups), then the correct notation is $A\oplus\overline{A}$ ($A\times \overline{A}$), respectively.

Answer (score 3):

As a set, the conformal symmetry algebra is $Vir \times \overline{Vir}$. As a vector space, it is $Vir \oplus \overline{Vir}$.

It is also useful to consider the universal enveloping algebra $U(Vir)$, whose generators are products of Virasoro generators of the type $\prod_i L_{m_i}$. This is now an associative algebra, instead of a Lie algebra. Then we have $U(Vir \times \overline{Vir}) = U(Vir) \otimes \overline{U(Vir)}$.

So physicists' writings are right and consistent, provided you accept that $Vir$ may mean various different things (including $U(Vir)$) depending on the context.

Comment: Can you tell me why one may want to consider that universal enveloping algebra, or point me to some text?

Comment: Elements of $U(Vir)$ are used for building descendent states, as in $L_{-1}L_{-2}|\text{primary}\rangle$. Also, the Sugawara construction expresses the Virasoro algebra as a subalgebra of the universal enveloping algebra of your affine Lie algebra. Also, W-algebras are in general not Lie algebras, the commutator of two generators needs not be a linear combination of generators.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring fineprints, the take-home message is that there are basically only 2 correct notations:

1. $G\times H$ for the [direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) or [Cartesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) product of Lie groups$^1$ $G$ and $H$.
2. $\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{h}$ for the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$.

For details and fineprints, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206840/2451) related Phys.SE post. [${\rm Vir}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra) is an infinite-dimensional Lie algebra, so one should use $\oplus$.

--

$^1$ Let us for simplicity assume that the Lie groups are *not* vector spaces, which are often the case.

Comment: In the math literature one sometimes find $G\oplus H$ as a notation for the direct product of two groups, with underlying set the Cartesian product, and with the obvious binary operation. (This notation is more common with rings than with groups though).

Comment: Which math literature? Which page?

Comment: Homology groups, for example. See e.g. [Künneth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem).

Comment: (Direct products and direct sums are regarded as being the same, except if the number of factors/summands is infinite, in which case the direct sum is by definition the set of sequences of compact support).

Comment: That seems to be for additively written (abelian) groups. Here we are for simplicity only discussing multiplicatively written Lie groups.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to point out that $G\oplus H$ is technically not incorrect, and is indeed sometimes used.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of notation. Suppose $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two (Lie) groups of dimension $d_1$ and $d_2$. We all know the natural way to construct the direct sum of these groups: it's a group of dimension $d_1 + d_2$ that mathematicians usually denote as $G_2 \oplus G_2$. However, physicists usually just write $G_1 \times G_2$. The same holds for (Lie) algebras. Moreover, in the physics literature it is rare to distinguish the Lie algebra from its group, unless there is a possible ambiguity or confusion that could arise.

Comment: Lie groups don't necessarily have a vector space structure, so the direct sum is meaningless. Whereas algebras are vector spaces by definition and the direct sum is well defined.