# Missing complex conjugate in (1/2,1/2) representation of Lorentz group Ticciati QFT

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, complex-numbers

I've been working through some computations involving representations of the Lorentz group (now using the fantastic Ticciati QFT textbook).

After some work, Ticciati gives the following formula
$$D^{j_{1},j_{2}}(X_{i})=D^{j_{1}}(T_{i})\otimes \mathbf{I}_{2j_{2}+1}+\mathbf{I}_{2j_{1}+1}\otimes D^{j_{2}}(T_{i}),$$
where $X_{i}$ are the generators of the Lorentz group written in the mathematicians convention without the extra factor of i, and the $T_{i}$ are the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ matrices.

I've computed $D^{0,1/2}(X_{k})$ and $D^{1/2,0}(X_{k})$, obtaining $-\frac{i}{2}\sigma_{k}$ in each case. This result agrees with what Ticciati gets in eq (6.7.9).

The issue arrives when I compute $D^{1/2,1/2}$. I know that I will have to perform a change of basis  using the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients, however, I only end up with the correct matrix if I add a complex conjugate to the formula Ticciati gives: $$D^{j_{1},j_{2}}(X_{i})=D^{j_{1}}(T_{i})\otimes \mathbf{I}_{2j_{2}+1}+\mathbf{I}_{2j_{1}+1}\otimes (D^{j_{2}}(T_{i}))^{*}.$$

I found another post: [Proof that $(1/2,1/2)$ Lorentz group representation is a 4-vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321292/)   Which does the same, however, the author of this post has not explained why this complex conjugate appears.

I tried to derive the formula using the complexified Lorentz algebra $$A_{k}=\frac{1}{2}(X_{k}+iB_{k}), \qquad C_{k}=\frac{1}{2}(X_{k}-iB_{k}),$$ and then embedding reps into the product space $\mathbf{C}^{(2j_{1}+1)(2j_{2}+1)}$ by writing $$D^{j_{1},j_{2}}(A_{k})=D^{j_{1}}(T_{k})\otimes \mathbf{I}_{2j_{2}+1}$$ and $$D^{j_{1},j_{2}}(C_{k})=\mathbf{I}_{2j_{1}+1}\otimes D^{j_{2}}(T_{k}).$$ Unfortunately I still get the same issue! There must be something that I'm not understanding! Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit: I give here an explicit calculation for $X_{1}$ using the complex conjugate.

$D^{1/2,1/2}(X_{1})=\frac{-i}{2}\sigma_{1}\otimes \mathbf{I}_{2}+\mathbf{I}_{2}\otimes (\frac{-i}{2}\sigma_{1})^{*}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & \frac{-i}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-i}{2} \\
\frac{-i}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{-i}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{i}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{i}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{i}{2} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{i}{2} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then the author in the post I linked above uses the following matrix to change basis (if someone could explain where this matrix is obtained that would be very helpful!):
$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & i & -i & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Then I get
$U^{-1}D^{1/2,1/2}(X_{1})U=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}=-iJ_{1}$

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of $S$ in Eq. 6.7.1, you can observe first that it is defined using the complex generators for the Lorentz group, $T_r, \bar{T}_r$, which are given before Homework 6.3.9. (where the $X_i$ and $B_i$ are defined), and second that the complex elements $\bar{T}_r$ are sent to $\tau_r$ not $\bar{\tau}$ so the conjugation is included therein.

Then Eq. 6.7.6 tells you what the representation matrix of each generator is, so you should be able to verify that $D_{1/2,1/2}(X)= X$, for a generic element $X\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. You need to use both rules, which you do not seem to be using.

Comment: See the edit I added.