# Direct Product vs Tensor Product

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations

I am confused in the notation on page 67 and page 70 a text (http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~tseng/teaching/b2/b2-lectures-2018.pdf), whether it's talking about a direct product or an outer product:

1. On page 67, it mentioned that

   > "you can take a direct product of two $j = 1/2$ representations"

   and build representations of higher j.
2. On page 70, it mentioned

   > "we can think of [the Lorentz Group] as the direct product $SU(2) \times SU(2)$."

In each of the above, does the author mean Direct Product or Tensor Product?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: “The universe is an enormous direct product of representations of symmetry groups.” – *Steven Weinberg* .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. On p. 67 Tseng means a [tensor product of representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations).
2. On  p. 70 Tseng means a [direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups).

   Note however that the actual statement about the Lorentz group is wrong/imprecise as explained in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.

   Concerning direct product vs. tensor product of groups, see also my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99305/2451).

Answer (score 1):

In both the cases the author is talking about direct product. Addition of two angular momentums $j_1$ and $j_2$ is represented using the direct product of the two angular momentum spaces. The wave functions or kets in the product space are represented using tensor product notation.