# Direct product and tensor product in representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to get some group theory basics from [Wu-Ki Tung, "Group Theory in Physics"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Group_Theory_in_Physics.html?id=O89tgpOBO04C&redir_esc=y). I'm having some trouble with his definitions of direct and tensor products of representations and representation spaces.

He defines

> *"the direct product space $U \times V$ consists of all linear combinations of the orthonormal basis vectors $\{\hat{w}_k; k = (i, j); i = 1,...,n_\mu;
> j = 1,...,n_\nu\}$ where $\hat{w}_k$, can be regarded as the “formal product” $\hat{w}_k=\hat{u}_i\cdot\hat{v}_j$"*

but to me, this looks a lot like a tensor product, since the dimension of $W$ would be $n_\mu n_\nu$ instead of $n_\mu+n_\nu$ that is what it'd like for my direct product (or direct sum, since we're talking about vector spaces).

He then says

> *"The direct product space $V_m \times V_m \times ... \times V_m$ involving $n$ factors of $V$ shall be referred to as the tensor space and denoted by $V^n_m$"*

but don't you need a tensor product to define the tensor space?

Lastly, he says that the *direct product representation* can be decomposed like $D^{\mu\times\nu}=\bigoplus_\lambda a_\lambda D^\lambda$. This seems correct, but since my two other questions, I'm doubting that I understand this too.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/447342/50583 Some physicists are really bad at keeping the mathematical notions of direct product and tensor product straight (presumably because the natural representation of the *direct product of groups* $G\times H$ is the *tensor product of representation spaces* $V_G\otimes V_H$. See also Qmechanic's answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/206849/50583

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of several questions linked above. Most physicists use direct product for tensor product, instead of Cartesian product, as they deal with vector spaces and linear operators/representations of both Lie algebras and exponentials of their elements. Cf [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).