# Representation theoretic constraints in SUSY algebra

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, supersymmetry, spinors

Let's try to build from scratch the SUSY commutator $[Q_\alpha^I, P_\mu]$. We know that the result of this commutator must be a fermonic generator belonging to $(1/2, 0)\otimes(1/2,1/2) \simeq (1, 1/2)\oplus (0, 1/2)$, so that I am allowed to write
\begin{equation}
[Q_\alpha^i, P_\mu] = A_{\alpha \mu}^i + B_{\alpha \mu}^i,
\end{equation}
with a priori two arbitrary sets of fermionic generators in the relevant irreps of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Since there are no $(1, 1/2)$ sermonic operators I can set $A=0$, so that
\begin{equation}
[Q_\alpha^i, P_\mu] = B_{\alpha \mu}^i.
\end{equation}
Since for each choice of indices $B_{\alpha \mu}^i$ must be in $(0, 1/2)$, I can write it as a linear combination of the $\bar{Q}^{\dot{\alpha} j}$s, thus
\begin{equation}
[Q_\alpha^i, P_\mu] = b^{ij}_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}\mu}\bar{Q}^{\dot{\alpha} j}.
\end{equation}
Now, for each choice of $i,j$ and $\mu$, we have a 2x2 complex matrix $b^{ij}_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}\mu}$, which we can then expand on the basis of such matrices given by the Pauli matrices, hence
\begin{equation}
[Q_\alpha^i, P_\mu] = b^{ij}_{\mu \nu}(\sigma^\nu)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}\bar{Q}^{\dot{\alpha} j}.
\end{equation}
It is not so obvious to me that $b$ must be proportional to the identity in the $\mu \nu$ indices as is assumed in every discussion of such commutators (e.g. [Constructing SUSY algebra via index structure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130397/constructing-susy-algebra-via-index-structure?rq=1)).

Nevertheless, Lorentz transforming both sides of the equation and using the mathematical identity $D_{(1/2,0)}(\Lambda)^{-1}\sigma ^\mu D_{(0, 1/2)}(\Lambda) = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\; \nu}\sigma^\nu $, consistency requires that $[\Lambda, b^{ij}]_{\mu \nu}=0$ for all $\Lambda$, thus $b^{ij}_{\mu \nu}=b^{ij}\delta_{\mu\nu}$, and
\begin{equation}
[Q_\alpha^i, P_\mu] = b^{ij}(\sigma_\mu)_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}}\bar{Q}^{\dot{\alpha} j}
\end{equation}
as expected (not by me but by everyone else, apparently).

My question is then:

**is there a way to rigorously prove that the index structure one would naively guess is the right one without having to go through the burden of checking consistency every single time?**

I'm interested in this since for more complicated (anti)commutators I cannot find a way to reproduce the natural index structure as I managed above. For instance the equation (2.72) of Bertolini's "Lectures on Supersymmetry" ([https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/susycourse.pdf](https://people.sissa.it/%7Ebertmat/susycourse.pdf)),
\begin{equation}
\{Q_\alpha ^i, Q_\beta^j\}=\epsilon_{\alpha \beta} Z^{ij} + \epsilon_{\beta \gamma}(\sigma^{\mu \nu})_\alpha ^{\; \gamma} J_{\mu \nu} Y^{ij}
\end{equation}
is almost completely mysterious to me.