# What is the difference between the $Spin(3,1)$ group and the $SO(3,1)$ group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

What is the difference between the $Spin(3,1)$ group and the $SO(3,1)$ group?

Answer (score 9):

1. The [spin group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $Spin^+(3,1;\mathbb{R})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the [double cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) of the [restricted Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Restricted_Lorentz_group) $SO^+(3,1;\mathbb{R})$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.
2. The spin group $Spin(3,1;\mathbb{R})$ is the double cover of the special Lorentz group $SO(3,1;\mathbb{R})$.
3. The [pin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group) $Pin(3,1;\mathbb{R})$ is the double cover of the Lorentz group $O(3,1;\mathbb{R})$.

References:

1. M. Rausch de Traubenberg, *Clifford Algebras in Physics,* [arXiv:hep-th/0506011](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506011); p. 9.

Comment: One might want to add that $Spin(3,1)$ is the universal cover of $SO^+(3,1)$ *by definition*, and is isomorphic to $SL(2,{\mathbb C})$ only by accident.

Comment: @WillO: Right .

Comment: @WillO one question: so the spin group is *defined* as the universal cover of $SO^+(3,1)$ instead of as the double cover? This means it is defined as what we get when we exponentiate the Lie algebra of $SO(3,1)$? I thought it was defined as the double cover instead.

Comment: @user1620696 :  The fundamental group of $SO^+(3,1)$ is ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$, so the  double cover and the universal cover are the same.  You can either first prove that the two covers are the same and then define the Spin group to be this common value, or you can first define the Spin group to be one or the other cover and then prove that both covers are the same.  Nothing depends on this.