# Lorentz Transformation Corresponding to element of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Suppose we map each 4-vector $V \in M^4$, where $M^4$ is the Minkowski space, to a $2 \times 2$ Hermitian matrix $$ V= V^μ σ_μ $$ where $σ^0$ is the identity $2 \times 2$ matrix and $σ_i$ are the Pauli matrices. We see that the determinant of $V$ is $η_{μν} V^μ V^ν$, where $η_{μν}=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$ is the Minkowski metric. 
It is quite easy to find the inverse map: $$V^μ = \frac12 Tr (V σ_μ).$$

Any transformation
\begin{equation}
 {V} \rightarrow {V}^{\prime}=\alpha {V} \alpha^{*} \tag{1}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
with $a$ a complex $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $1$, and $a^*$ its Hermitian adjoint, preserves the determinant, ie $ det(V^{'})=det(V)$.
Hence it corresponds to a Lorentz transormation $Λ^μ _ν$ (an element of $SO(3,1)$) : $$V^{\prime \mu}=\Lambda_{\nu}^{\mu} V^{\nu} $$

What I am trying to prove is the form of the Lorentz transformation, given the transformation of the matrix $V$ by $a$. I know that the result is:

$$\Lambda_{\nu}^{\mu}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr} \alpha \sigma_{\nu} \alpha^{*} \sigma_{\mu} \tag{2} $$

I tried taking equation (1) to get:

$$Λ^μ_ν V^ν σ_μ = α V^μ σ_μ α^* $$

which looks promising. Now this has to holds for all $V^μ$, but I'm not sure what this allows me to do.

Comment: The 3 and 4 D cases are given [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/3P2Lb.pdf) (sections 2.2 and 4.3.1).

Comment: he gets to $\sigma_{\mu} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\mu}=A \sigma_{\nu} A^{\dagger}$, i suppose by the relation that I wrote. But what is this exactly? On the left hand side we have a 2x2 matrix times a four vector, so is this a kronecker product of matrices? On the right hand side we have a 2x2 matrix or the kronecker product of a 2x2 by a 4-vector. And how do we get from this to the final result?

Comment: Hint: First multiply eq. (1) with $\sigma_{\mu}$ and then take trace on both sides to get to eq. (2). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451