# How to define a map from $\mathrm{SO}^+(1, 3)$ to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, group-theory, representation-theory

To explain how spinors transform under rotation people often use that $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ is a double cover   $\mathrm{SO}^+(1, 3)$, that is there is a surjective homomorphism $\lambda:\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow \mathrm{SO}^+(1, 3)$ with $\ker(\lambda)=
\{-1,+1\}$ where $\ker$ means kernel.

I am not familiar with this but, apparently we can show, experimentally, using neutron interferometer, that if we rotate our measurement apparatus by an angle $2\theta$, then the spinor is rotated by an angle $\theta$.

Now by the last statement we should have a map from $\mathrm{SO}^+(1, 3)$ to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$.
How can we define this map? By definition of a function each object has a unique image, so how can we define this map?
Apparently the only way to solve this is to say for example that $2 \pi$ rotation and a $4\pi$ rotation are deafferents. Am I right?

Comment: There isn't any such map, at least rigourously. Physically, we would say that we have a double valued map. But of course, mathematically, maps are always single valued ...

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah   Say $2\pi$ in physical space then which of the angle in the spinor space should we associate to this $-\pi$ or $\pi$? There should be so kind of relation or I am wrong?

Comment: It's a [double-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451 and links therein.

Comment: We don't use 'double-valued functions' in this way, they are a way of speaking when physicists were attempting to understand spinors; instead, we use double covers, so Spin(1,3) double covers SO(1,3).

Comment: @QMechanic: Although those are said to be multi-valued functions, they actually aren't; they are simply functions that map to the power set of the target. This doesn't work here, since when we make a full rotation in the domain, the target value reverses it's value, there is no ordinary function or 'double-valued function' that can do this, because every domain value must map to one and the same value, whether this value is singly valued or multiply valued. In order to get the correct behaviour, we need to incorporate the path history. Its simpler to use double coverings; see previous comment

Comment: @ Mozibur Ullah what do you mean by path history?

Answer (score 4):

> Now by the last statement we should have a map from $\mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$. How can we define this map?

That's not quite right.  What that statement says is that we should have a map from **paths**$^\ddagger$ on $\mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ to **paths** on $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$.  In other words, if we start at some point $p\in \mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ and follow some continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$, then we should be able to "lift" that to a path $\Gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$.  This is indeed possible, provided we make a choice of starting point for $\Gamma$.

More precisely, let $h:\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)\rightarrow \mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ be our surjective homomorphism, let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ be a continuous curve, and let $p\in \mathrm{preim}_h\big(\gamma(0)\big)$.  Then there is a unique continuous curve $\Gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ such that $\Gamma(0)=p$ and $h\circ \Gamma = \gamma$.

[image]

Explicitly, consider the following path through $\mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$:

$$\gamma: [0,2\pi]\ni t \mapsto \pmatrix{1 &0&0&0\\0&\cos( t) & -\sin( t) & 0\\ 0 & \sin( t) & \cos( t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

Let $\Gamma(0) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$.  Given the homomorphism which is explicitly written out in Jeanbaptiste's nice answer, we see that $\gamma$ lifts to the curve

$$\Gamma:[0,2\pi]\ni t \mapsto \pmatrix{e^{-it/2} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{it/2}}$$

It's straightforward to check that $h\circ \Gamma = \gamma$, but we observe that while $\gamma(2\pi)=\gamma(0)$, $\Gamma(2\pi)=-\Gamma(0)$.

---

> $^\ddagger$Is the reason for you to say that we should maps path because, for example, to go from 0 to $2\pi$ we should go on a continuous path?

I think the confusion arises because we tend to think of rotations as continuous actions, like turning your experimental apparatus.  But actually, a rotation is not a process, but rather the **result** of a process.  In the language of my answer, a process is a *path*, and the resulting rotation is the *endpoint* of that path.

If you look down at a coffee cup and turn it $180^\circ$ clockwise, you obtain the same result as if you'd turned it $180^\circ$ counterclockwise. These two processes result in the same rotation of your cup, but they are clearly different processes. Similarly, turning your cup by an angle of $360^\circ$ results in the same rotation as not turning it at all.

When we hear statements like "a $360^\circ$ rotation sends a spinor $\psi$ to $-\psi$," we tend say to ourselves "wait, but a $360^\circ$ rotation is the identity transformation, so how does it change $\psi$ at all?" This confusion is a result of mistaking a process with its result.  The **process** of continuously rotating a coffee cup by $360^\circ$ results in the same final configuration as the **process** of not touching the cup at all.  But spinors and coffee cups are not the same.  Rotations on the former are implemented by (representations of) elements of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ while rotations on the latter are implemented by (representations of) elements of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and the aformentioned process does *not* have the same effect on spinors as the identity transformation does.

Incidentally, if you've ever turned a multi-turn knob you are already very familiar with this idea.  If you turn the volume knob on a car stereo by $360^\circ$ to the right, the knob will have returned to the same configuration while the stereo system will not have.  You may argue, "well yes, but the stereo has some *internal* degrees of freedom which shouldn't be expected to remain unchanged even though the *external* degree of freedom (i.e. the knob) has returned to its original configuration," but I'd counter with the fact that the same is true for fermionic particles, and the internal degree of freedom is precisely the spinor part of the particle's state.

Comment: the reason for you to say that we should maps path is because , for example, to go from $0$ to $2\pi$ we should go on a continuous path?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I have updated my answer to discuss this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Jeanbaptiste Roux contains the exact form of the mapping (Lie group homomorphism) from $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ to $\mathrm{SO}^{+}(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ (the latter is also denoted in the literature as $\mathfrak{L}^{+}_{\uparrow}$ or $\mathfrak{Lor}(1,3)$). As a mapping, it is not bijective, so it does not an inverse in the proper mathematical sense (think of the function $f(x) = x^2 \vert f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{+}$, where there is no $f^{-1}$), but, however, the equation

$$\Lambda^{\mu}_{~\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}\left(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}A^{\dagger}\sigma_{\nu}A\right) \tag{1}$$

can be "reversed" to

$$ \displaystyle{A=\pm\frac{\Lambda^{\mu}_{~\nu} \sigma_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}}{[\mathrm{det}\left(\Lambda^{\mu}_{~\nu} \sigma_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}\right)]^{\frac{1}{2}}}}\tag{2}$$

The proof of $(2)$ starting from $(1)$ is offered by [Müller-Kirsten & Wiedemann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814293423) on pages 70-71 of the first edition of the book. The proof should also be in the second edition, whose A m a z o n link I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $\tilde{\sigma}^\mu \equiv \tilde{\sigma}_\mu$ the Pauli matrices, with $\sigma^0=\text{Id}$ that does not change when we raise or lower the index. There exist an $M$ isomorphism between the set of $2\times 2$ hermitian matrices and $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$:
\begin{align*}
M : \mathbb{R}^{1,3} & \longrightarrow MH(2,\mathbb{C})
\\
x^\mu &\longmapsto C= x\cdot \sigma
\end{align*}
With $M^{-1}$ defined by:
\begin{align*}
M^{-1} : MH(2,\mathbb{C}) & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{1,3}
\\
C &\longmapsto x^\mu= \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}(\tilde{\sigma}^\mu C)
\end{align*}
With the pseudo-norm given by $x \cdot x=\det C$. The matrices $C$ transform under $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ according to the law $C \rightarrow A^\dagger C A=C'$. Since $\det C=\det C'$, we have the following equalities:
\begin{align*}
{x'}^\mu &= \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\tilde{\sigma}^\mu A^\dagger CA)
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(\tilde{\sigma}^\mu A^\dagger \sigma_\nu A)x^\nu
\end{align*}
We then can define a relation between matrices from $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $SO^{+}(1,3)$:
\begin{align*}
\phi : SL(2,\mathbb{C}) &\longrightarrow O^{+}(1,3)
\\
A,-A & \longmapsto \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(\tilde{\sigma}^\mu A^\dagger \sigma_\nu A)
\end{align*}
Then $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the double cover of $SO^{+}(1,3)$.

Comment: what i am asking is a map from $O(1,3)$ to $SL(2,C)$ not the contrary

Comment: @amiltonmoreira As QMechanic has noted, there is no such map.

Comment: @NDewolf there should be a  map since experimentally  we can show that $2\pi$ correspond to $\pi$ in the spinor space and $4\pi$  correspond to $2\pi$ in the spinor space. To  be no contradiction $2\pi$ rotation should be different from $4\pi$ rotation

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Sorry I've misread your question.. However, you can see here that there can't be any $\phi^{-1}$ since it is not a bijection. As Qmechanic pointed out, it should be a multivalued function.

Comment: @NDewolf: That was me that pointed out that there was no such group morphism. QMechanic actually supported the other view when he mentioned 'double-valued functions' and linked into an older post, which I didn't bother looking at given his misconstrual of a double-valued function in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Since passive rotation and active rotation are equivalent, if we take the active point of view things should be more clear. What  I mean is this : instead of taking the approach where it is the apparatus that is rotating we take the approach that is the spinor which is rotating.