# Coverings of the Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory

I noticed the followings:

1. $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a double cover of $SO(1,3)$.
2. $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a double cover of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$
3. $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $SO^+(1,3)$ which is the restricted Lorentz group.

I would expect that $PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong SO(1,3)$, not $PSL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong SO^+(1,3)$ since $SO(1,3)$ is not isomorphic to $SO^+(1,3)$.

Actually I think $SO(1,3)$ should be a 4-fold cover of $SO^+(1,3)$.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Claim (1) is wrong. Where did you see it?

Comment: I have seen it in the section 'Homomorphisms and Isomorphisms' in the wikipedia page of Lorentz group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group).

Comment: Do not trust anything you see on wikipedia. How about you get hold of a good book? Try B. Thaller's "The Dirac equation" or the 2nd volume of Cornwell's group theory treatise. They treat coverings of the Lorentz groups in 1+3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the double cover of the restricted [Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$, not the proper Lorentz group $SO(1,3;\mathbb{R})$. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post. Be aware that notation and terminology may differ for different authors.