# Understanding spinors, double cover and professor's expanation

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, spinors

I'm following an introductory course in QFT, and we are facing the spin group part. I think that most of the details are left apart because it would take too much time to be developd, and my profesor doesn't really look like "an expert" in the sector to say it all. I think he just gives us facts, but me I want to understand those facts.

Here is what he wrote:

Representation of Spin$(1, 3)$ which is the double vocer of $SO(1, 3)$. It turns out that Spin$(1, 3) = SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, hence $SO(1, 3) \equiv SL(2, \mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2$.

$SO(1, 3)$ is homomorphic to $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ but not isomorphic since it is a $1-2$ map, that is $A, B \in SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, then $\Lambda(A)\Lambda(B) = \Lambda(AB)$ where $\Lambda$ are Lorentz's matrices.

Also to "show" the double cover question, he drew a segment, from point $a$ to point $b$, and then he drew a circle around the segment in order to make the segment a chord of this circle saying "it passes through two points of the segment, so it double covers it".

**EDIT**: I got answers of two of the questions here: [SL$(2, \mathbb{C})$ double cover of SO${}^{+}$(1, 3)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669776/sl2-mathbbc-double-cover-of-so1-3)

My remaining doubts:

- Finally, $SO^+(1, 3)$ is homomorphic to $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ but not isomorphic since it is a $1-2$ map. Why the example with Lorentz's matrices?
- to "show" the double cover question, he drew a segment, from point $a$ to point $b$, and then he drew a circle around the segment in order to make the segment a chord of this circle saying "it passes through two points of the segment, so it double covers it". WHAT?

I recognise it's a lot to ask for, but trust me when I tell you that I have been searching for two days in books, notes and so on, and my professor is just rude and not availabel to explanations.

Comment: I know it is very unprofessional to give YouTube links, but these explanations are spot on, for a beginner: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACZC_XEyg9U&t=18s), [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5soqexrwqY&t=4s).

Comment: I find that a book on General Relativity in the way in which SO(1,3) relates to SU(2) is a good way to start. For example Ryder's book on GR section 2.1.2 (very) quickly reviews this. And other QFT books also review the subject when studying field representations and spin. It might also help something like https://hal.science/hal-00502337/document

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're really asking here. 1. What do you mean by "the example with Lorentz' matrices"? $\mathrm{SO}(1,3)$ *is* the group of Lorentz matrices! 2. If you project this circle down to its chord (just orthogonal projection onto that line) every point on the line is the image of two points on the circle (except the two points where the chord intersects the circle). Why your professor thought this would illuminate anything is not an objective question we can answer.

Comment: Also, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/50583 for our most popular question on the finite-dimensional representation theory of $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, my question was blurred. I meant: "why the example with Lorentz's matrices, written in that way, should tell me that those groups are not isomorphic?"

Comment: I still don't know what "example with Lorentz's matrices" you mean, I don't see any example anywhere here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What he wrote: $\Lambda(A)\Lambda(B) = \Lambda(AB)$. Why should this tell me there is no isomorphism?

Comment: I don't know why you'd call that an "example", nor do I even understand what that equation is supposed to mean. How is $\Lambda(A)$ defined? Is this supposed to be the projection map from the cover onto the base?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Good, then it's the two of us.

Comment: @ACuriousMind On second thoughts, I think it's rather obvious: given two elements in $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, then the Lorentz's transformation of $A$ times the Lorentz's transformation of $B$ equals the Lorentz's transformation of $AB$. 

Again: why should this tell me there is no isomorphism between the two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is $Spin(1,3)$ the double cover of $SO(1,3)$? You have first to realize that $Spin(1,3)$ is related to how spinor/fermion $\psi$ transforms, whereas $SO(1,3)$ is related to how vector $V$ transforms.

The essence of "double cover" can be elucidated pretty clearly, when vector $V$  is expressed as  $V=\Sigma_\mu  V_\mu \gamma^\mu$, where $\gamma^\mu$ is the Dirac Gamma operator. Let's look at the different ways spinor/fermion $\psi$ and vector $V$ transform under a rotation:
$$
Spin(1,3) \space rotation: \quad \psi \rightarrow e^{iT\theta/2}\psi,  \\
SO(1,3) \space rotation: \quad V \rightarrow  e^{iT\theta/2}Ve^{-iT\theta/2} , 
$$
where $T$ is a rotation generator of the Lie algebra.

Because of the double-sided nature of $e^{iT\theta/2}Ve^{-iT\theta/2}$, a $\theta/2$ rotation of a fermion is translated to a $\theta$ rotation of a vector. For example, when the $\theta/2 = \pi$
$$
\psi \rightarrow e^{iT\pi}\psi =e^{i\pi}\psi = -\psi\\
V \rightarrow  e^{iT\pi}Ve^{-iT\pi}= e^{2iT\pi}V= e^{2i\pi}V = V
$$
for any rotation generator $T$ anti-commuting with $V$ (we also used the property that $T$ squares to unit operator $I$: $T^2 = I$).

So when a fermion is half way around a circle, a vector has already finished the whole circle rotation. And when a fermion finishes the full circle, a vector has already went around the circle **twice**. That is what we mean by "$Spin(1,3)$ is a double cover of $SO(1,3)$".

---

Added note:

If you are curious enough, you might want to ask why we demand that vector $V$ should transform as $V \rightarrow  e^{iT\theta/2}Ve^{-iT\theta/2}$ and why $V$  is expressed as  $V=\Sigma_\mu  V_\mu \gamma^\mu $.

Well, it has to do with how we build a typical vector from spinor-biliear in Quantum Field Theory (QFT):
$$
V_\mu = \bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu \psi
$$
which are just the coefficients of the vector $\gamma^\mu$ components of
$$
\psi\bar{\psi}
$$
How does $\psi\bar{\psi}$ transform? Based on the spinor transform property $\psi \rightarrow e^{iT\theta/2}\psi$, you can easy verify that:
$$
\psi\bar{\psi} \rightarrow  e^{iT\theta/2}\psi\bar{\psi}e^{-iT\theta/2} 
$$
So the transformation property is dictated by how spinor $\psi$ and vector $V_\mu$ are related in QFT.

In other words, spinor $\psi$ transforms single-sidedly as $Spin(1,3)$ and (the vector portion of) spinor-bilinear $\psi\bar{\psi}$ transforms double-sidedly as $SO(1,3)$. That's the whole story. Pretty neat, huh?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you really much!