# What isomorphisms does $SO(3,1)$ have?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

The double cover of $SO(4)$ is isomorphic to $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, which might be related to $SO(3,1)$.

Also, I have seen that $so(3,1)=Cl^2(3,1)$. However, the notation confused me a bit, does the super index of 2 means $Cl(3,1)\times Cl(3,1)$? If so, how does one prove that $so(3,1)=Cl^2(3,1)$?

What other isomophisms or equalities does $SO(3,1)$ have?

Comment: Seen where? Which page?

Comment: SO(4) is not isomorphic to SU(2)×SU(2), because they are not the same topological manifolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. More generally, for a [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) $Cl(V,Q)$ over a $d$-dimensional vector space $V$ with a quadratic form $Q$ of signature $(s,t)$ there exists a linear isomorphism $$Cl(V,Q)~\cong~ \bigwedge\! V\tag{1}$$ with the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) $\bigwedge\! V$. Both sides of eq. (1) are $2^d$-dimensional. In particular for quadratic elements
   $$Cl^2(V,Q)~\cong~ \bigwedge\!{}^2 V~\cong~ so(V,Q),\tag{2}$$
   where $so(V,Q)$ is the $\frac{d(d-1)}{2}$-dimensional special [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) associated with $(V,Q)$.

   In OP's case $(V,Q)$ is spacetime endowed with the Minkowski metric.
2. Concerning group isomorphisms: The restricted [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group)
   $$SO^+(3,1;\mathbb{R})~\cong~ PSL(2,\mathbb{C}),$$ cf .e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.